# How do programs like Apache Airflow/ Luigi determine shortest path and how does that relate to graph theory?

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal, scheduling

I am looking for a simple layman's term explanation on how do programs like Apache Airflow or Luigi (or any Task/ETL schedulers) determine the shortest path to complete a certain task and make it possible to parallelize it? And how does that, if any, relate to graph theory?

Comment: If it's a proprietary system with closed source code, we can't really know. You could however ask for possible ways of solving some problem.